# Angularjs get json not working in google map

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, json

I want to show you the list of the places in the area on the map. And with the following code I can show this, but I can not figure out how to extract the data from MySQL. How can I change the part of $ scope.names below with ajax.php.

This html code is working perfectly:

```js
var hotelApp = angular.module('hotelApp', [])
        hotelApp.controller('ContentControler', function ($scope, $http) {
     var imageUrl = base_url + 'marker.png';
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
        $scope.location_name = "";
     
    $http.get('properties.php').success(function(data) {
            $scope.namesx = data;
        });
      
        $scope.names = [{
            prop_Name: name,
            prop_Addr: '123 Easy Street',
            prop_Price: 325.00,
            prop_Dist: .25,
            prop_Desc: 'This is the First Location.',
            lat: 43.7000,
            long: -79.4000
        }, {
            prop_Name: 'Location 2',
            prop_Addr: '456 Easy Street',
            prop_Price: 114.00,
            prop_Dist: 3,
            prop_Desc: 'This is the Second Location.',
            lat: 40.6700,
            long: -73.9400
        }, {
            prop_Name: 'Location 3',
            prop_Addr: '789 Easy Street',
            prop_Price: 98.00,
            prop_Dist: 4,
            prop_Desc: 'This is the Third Location.',
            lat: 41.8819,
            long: -87.6278
        }, {
            prop_Name: 'Location 4',
            prop_Addr: '1011 Easy Street',
            prop_Price: 150.00,
            prop_Dist: 1,
            prop_Desc: 'This is the Fourth Location.',
            lat: 34.0500,
            long: -118.2500
        }, {
            prop_Name: 'Location 5',
            prop_Addr: '1213 Easy Street',
            prop_Price: 250.00,
            prop_Dist: 7,
            prop_Desc: 'This is the Firth Location.',
            lat: 36.0800,
            long: -115.1522
        }];
        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

        $scope.markers = [];

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 350});

        var createMarker = function (info) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
                title: info.prop_Name,
       deniz: info.prop_Addr,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
       
            });
      
            marker.content = '<div id="iw-container"><div class="iw-content"><div class="iw-subTitle">' + '<li>' + info.prop_Desc + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Addr + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Price + '</li>' + '<li>' + info.prop_Dist + '</li>' + '</div></div></div>';

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent('<div class="iw-subTitle">' + marker.title + '</div>' + marker.content);
                infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
            });
      
      google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'click', function() {
       infoWindow.close($scope.map, marker);
      });
      
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
      
      google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {

      // Reference to the DIV that wraps the bottom of infowindow
      var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

      /* Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div style-iw.
       * We use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
       * and took advantage of the existing reference .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
      */
      var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

      // Removes background shadow DIV
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

      // Removes white background DIV
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

      // Moves the infowindow 115px to the right.
      iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '115px'});

      // Moves the shadow of the arrow 76px to the left margin.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

      // Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

      // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'silver 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1'});

      // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
      var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

      // Apply the desired effect to the close button
      iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});

      // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum height, then the gradient is removed.
      if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
        $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
      }

      // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button after the mouseout event. This function reverses this event to the desired value.
      iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
      });
      });

        }

        for (i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
            createMarker($scope.names[i]);
        }

        $scope.openInfoWindow = function (e, selectedMarker) {
            e.preventDefault();
            google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
        }
     
     
     
     
     $scope.goster = function (e, selectedMarker) {
            e.preventDefault();
      selectedMarker.setIcon(imageUrl);
      selectedMarker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
     
     $scope.gizle = function (e, selectedMarker) {
            e.preventDefault();
      selectedMarker.setIcon(null);
            selectedMarker.setAnimation(null);
        }
     
        //Max Location Price
        $scope.maxPrice = 500;
        $scope.priceRangeFilter = function (location) {
            return location.prop_Price <= $scope.maxPrice;
        };
        //Max POI Radius
        $scope.maxRadius = 15;
        $scope.radiusRangeFilter = function (location) {
            return location.prop_Dist <= $scope.maxRadius;
        };

        $scope.$watch('nas',

        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            for (jdx in $scope.markers) {
                $scope.markers[jdx].setMap(null);
            }
            $scope.markers = [];
            for (idx in $scope.nas) {
                createMarker($scope.nas[idx]);
            }
        }, true);

    });
```

```css
#map {
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
}
.gm-style-iw {
 width: 350px !important;
 top: 15px !important;
 left: 0px !important;
 background-color: #fff;

 border: 1px solid silver;
 border-radius: 0px;
 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 48px 9px 14px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 48px 9px 14px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 48px 9px 14px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}
#iw-container {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#iw-container .iw-title {
 font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #48b5e9;
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
}
#iw-container .iw-title a{
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#iw-container .iw-content {
 width:330px;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin-right: 1px;
 color:#aaa;
 padding: 10px;
 max-height: 400px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.iw-content a{
 color:#777;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.iw-content img {
 margin: 0; 
}
.iw-subTitle {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 5px 0;
}
.iw-bottom-gradient {
 position: absolute;
 width: 326px;
 height: 25px;
 bottom: 10px;
 right: 18px;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html lang="tr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Airbnb Çalışmam</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVgASeglOFj8kUSEnVQVfr4vuaD1pVxI8&sensor=false&libraries=places" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
     var base_url = "http://www.odevi.org/test/airbnb/airbnb_map/";
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="hotelApp" ng-controller="ContentControler">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <h2>Filters</h2>
        <p>Location Name:
            <input type="text" ng-model="location_name">
        </p>
        <p>Maxium Price:
            <input type="text" ng-model="maxPrice">
        </p>
        <p>POI Search Radius:
            <input type="text" ng-model="maxRadius">
        </p>

     <div id="esra">tese</div>
     <div id="class" ng-repeat="marker in markers | orderBy : 'title'">
        <a href="#" ng-mouseover="goster($event, marker)" ng-mouseleave="gizle($event, marker)">{{marker.title}}-{{marker.deniz}}</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="x in nas = (names | filter:{prop_Name:location_name} | filter:priceRangeFilter | filter:radiusRangeFilter)"></div>    
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but i want get php mysql data with json. how to change $scope.names with ajax.php you can help me?

my ajax.php code:

```html
<?php
$response['success'] = false;
$dsn = "mysql:dbname=dname;host=localhost;charset=utf8;";
$db = new PDO($dsn, "dnames", "1111111");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_propertiesx");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!empty($result)) {
  $response['success'] = true;
  $response['data'] = $result;
  $ney = $response['data'];
}

echo json_encode($ney);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incoming data must first be encapsulated in the controller with an empty array, and the process must start and the request is completed. Simple:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.names = [];

    $scope.operation = function(data) {
        // operation data
    };

    $http.get('ajax.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.names = data;
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
            $scope.operation($scope.names[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that the result of your ajax.php is correct formated. Than check if the scope is applied after setting all the data. Try `$scope.$apply().`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing the map update after the call to the php script. First, make sure the data is returned. You can do this very easily with a breakpoint in chrome or just console.log(data); after the call. Second, if you see the data being returned and you are setting $scope.names to json data returned, you will probably need call $scope.$apply() to trigger the digest loop and for the $scope to pick up the new value of names and display it in the DOM. So please try adding the following after you set the $scope.names variable:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $scope.$apply();
});
```

This will trigger the digest loop if that is indeed the problem you are describing.

Comment: I have to do it this way? $http.get('ajax.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.names = data;
    });
 
setTimeout(function () {
   $scope.$apply();
});
it is not work :(

Comment: my ajax.php result: 
[{"prop_Name":"deniz","prop_Addr":"http:\/\/www.odevi.org\/resim-ekle\/personel\/7296\/1484234439_5_7296.jpg","prop_Price":"deneme 1","prop_Dist":"10.00","prop_Desc":"","lat":"36.8582389","lng":"30.631253499999957"},{"prop_Name":"mehmet","prop_Addr":"http:\/\/www.odevi.org\/resim-ekle\/personel\/7301\/1484299675_52_7301.jpg","prop_Price":"fdfdsf","prop_Dist":"10.00","prop_Desc":"","lat":"36.1582389","lng":"30.131253499999957"}]

Comment: setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
   $http.get('ajax.php').then(function(data) {
        $scope.names = data;
    });
 });
 }, 2000);
not working :(

Comment: I noticed your test data $scope.names uses the property "long" for longitude and the data returned from your service call uses "lng" as the name. Perhaps this is where things are failing. Make sure that mock data and the data returned from the service are in the same format. If the mock data is working then the data return, along with triggering the digest loop, should do the trick. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The scopes need to apply when the php-script returns the result. Try to minimate your're code first to bring the ajax-stuff working. After that re-write the code.